# How does a TableModelListener for a JTable work?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtable, listener

It's my first time having to work with a JTable. I pull data from a database via the DAO pattern, save it in a collection, read that collection and fill up my JTable with it. However I'm also working with the MVC pattern and don't know how to properly update my view, so the data added to the JTable actually shows up. I've read about ways to do it via an Observer or TableModelListener (I don't intend to discuss which rather to use). But I cannot find a single complete implementation or in-depth explanation of a working TableModelListener and Oracle docs never have been of much help to me.

Could someone explain to me how to properly implement a TableModelListener for me to update my view once all data has been writing into the JTable?

Here is my AbstractTableModel class:

```
    public class AbstractTableModel extends DefaultTableModel{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7354466553311529134L;

    private static Logger logger =     Logger.getLogger(AbstractTableModel.class);

    private static String col[] = { "Table", "UpdateCols", "AlterAuth",
            "DeleteAuth", "IndexAuth", "InsertAuth", "SelectAuth",     "UpdateAuth" };

    private static DefaultTableModel tableModel = new     DefaultTableModel(null, col);
    private static JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);

    public static JTable updateTable(DatenbankDaoImpl db) throws     SQLException, IOException {

        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                logger.debug(e);
            }
        });

        while (table.getRowCount() > 0) {
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(0);
        }

        for (DatenbankBean db1 : db.getDatenbank()) {
            String table = db1.getTable();
            String updatecols = db1.getUpdatecols();
            String alterauth = db1.getAlterauth();
            String deleteauth = db1.getDeleteauth();
            String indexauth = db1.getIndexauth();
            String insertauth = db1.getInsertauth();
            String selectauth = db1.getSelectauth();
            String updateauth = db1.getUpdateauth();

            Object[] data = {table, updatecols, alterauth, deleteauth,     indexauth, insertauth, selectauth, updateauth};
            tableModel.addRow(data);
            logger.debug("AbstractTableModel: " + data.toString());
        }
//      table.repaint();
        return table;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is a relationship between the `JTable` (view), `TableModel` (model) and the `TableModelListener` (observer).  Basically, it's the responsibility of the `TableModel` to generate appropriate `TableModelEvent`s based on changes made to the model. In most common cases, it's unlikely that you'll ever need to implement `TableModelListener` yourself, as when you apply a `TableModel` to the `JTable`, the `JTable` automatically registers a `TableModelListener` to it (and updates itself according to the model).

Comment: The `AbstractTableModel` provides a number of helper methods which makes it easy to generate model events based on the common functionality of the model (add/remove/update rows).  Typically this is where you'd interact

Comment: *"But I cannot find a single complete implementation or in-depth explanation of a working TableModelListener"* - `AbstractTableModel` and `JTable` would be the best starting point

Comment: "Oracle docs never have been of much help to me". That's really sad, especially if you intend to keep programming in Java.

Comment: *"However I'm also working with the MVC pattern and don't know how to properly update my view, so the data added to the JTable actually shows up"* - Swing is a type of MVC, you'll need to learn and understand how that works, which from reading your question, seems to be the core issue. Don't try and make the API work in way you want it to, work with the API in the way it was designed ... good or bad

Comment: Then how do I apply my TableModle class to my actual JTable in the view? My problem is that I do have a JTable and my TableModle class, but I don't know how to actually make them work together as I can't find any explanation on how to do that.

Comment: `so the data added to the JTable actually shows` - well that is the problem. You don't add data to the table. You add data to the TableModel. The model will then automatically tell the table to paint itself.

Comment: That is what I've done though. I've already looked into it when debugging. The data is added row by row. But it never shows up in my view, even when I explicitly tell it to repaint itself.

Answer (score 0):

What about this article it explains every part of it and is executable as well?

[Oracle on How to Write a Table Model Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/tablemodellistener.html)

Here are the basic parts:

Upon instantiation, each JTable object is passed a table model object that manages the data it displays. By default, a JTable object inherits a DefaultTable object if no custom TableModel object is specified, but by default, this model only manages strings. To handle objects, perform calculations, or to retrieve data from databases or other programs, you must design your own custom TableModel object, which implements the TableModel interface. See Creating a Table Model for details.

To detect changes to the data managed by a table model object, the JTable class needs to implement the TableModelListener interface, call addTableModelListener() to catch events, and then override tableChanged() to respond to listener events. See Listening for Data Changes for details

Comment: *"Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."* - sounds more like comment to me

Comment: I dont think that oracle will remove the basic tutorials from their website as long as they are selling it.

Comment: Since Java is now open sourced, and Oracle never "sold" it, I'd not be holding my breath on that point

Comment: They sell it nowadays ;)

Comment: I did already see this, but it's not really telling me too much.

Comment: As a programmer you often have to deal with unsatisfying documentation or such a like. Look at the source code. Write your own class that implements this interface. I know you can do it. It just has a single method.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListeningtoJTableEventswithaTableModelListener.htm

Comment: That did help quite a bit. However when calling "addTableModelListener" lile in the example I can only use the default TableModelListener class as a parameter and not my custom interface. Calling it on the default one, does not let me display the data either. I think the problem might be againg due to the MVC pattern. I have to somehow tell the table in my view to do the above and not the table inside my AbstractTableModel.